# TeX capacity exceeded

Tags: errors, programming

The following is a minimal example which demonstrates my problem. The error

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000] \end{latexresult}
```

is depending more or less on the number of codelines, not the actual code (therefore it is so long). One can comment out nearly any line and the error vanishes. I have no clue what could cause the problem.
I have mdframed in mind, but can not see what should cause the error.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{url}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\RequirePackage{mdframed}

\RequirePackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{latexcode}{}{}
\newenvironment{latexresult}{%
Result:
\mdframed[skipabove=6pt]%
}{
\endmdframed
\noindent
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}

\chapter{template demonstration}
\section{text markup}
\subsection{standard commands}
%
\begin{filecontents*}{democode}
The standard commands for font attributes:  
\textbf{bold}, \textit{italic}, \textsl{slanted},
\textsf{sans serif}, \textsc{small caps} and
\texttt{monospaced typewrite}.
And any combination of them:
\textit{\textbf{bold italic}},
\textsl{\textbf{bold slanted}},
\textsf{\textbf{bold sans serif}},
\textsc{\textbf{bold small caps}}
\textsl{\textsf{sans serif slanted}}. 
\end{filecontents*}

Code: 
\lstinputlisting{democode.tex}%
\begin{latexresult}%
\IfFileExists{democode.tex}{\input{democode.tex}}{}%
\end{latexresult}

\begin{filecontents*}{democode}
\url{http://www.dante.de} \\
\end{filecontents*}

\ifcsdef{url}{%
\subsection{package: url}

The url package provides a failsafe way to print
urls with characters not allowed by LaTeX.

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\begin{latexresult}%
\IfFileExists{democode.tex}{\input{democode.tex}}{}%
\end{latexresult}
\end{minipage}

The font used for this command can be set up in the preamble.
}{}%

\section{paragraph alignment}
\subsection{standard alignment}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\begin{latexresult}%
\IfFileExists{democode.tex}{\input{democode.tex}}{}%
\end{latexresult}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

EDIT:
I uncommented one line to let it compile again and got this filelist then:

```
*File List*
scrbook.cls 2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty 2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent ba
sics and keyval usage)
scrbase.sty 2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent
basics and keyval usage)
keyval.sty 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty 2011/03/09 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty 2011/05/30 v3.09a KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo 2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty 2011/06/16 v3.09a KOMA-Script package (type area)
url.sty 2006/04/12 ver 3.3 Verb mode for urls, etc.
etoolbox.sty 2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
etex.sty 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
filecontents.sty 2009/03/17 v1.2 Create an external file from within a LaTeX
document
mdframed.sty 2011/08/22 v0.8: mdframed
kvoptions.sty 2010/12/23 v3.10 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
ltxcmds.sty 2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty 2011/04/07 v1.13 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
etexcmds.sty 2011/02/16 v1.5 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
ifluatex.sty 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
calc.sty 2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
color.sty 2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
md-frame-0.mdf 2011/08/22 v0.8: md-frame-0
listings.sty 2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
lstmisc.sty 2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg 2007/02/22 1.4 listings configuration
supp-pdf.mkii
democode.tex
omscmr.fd 1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
democode.tex
democode.tex
***********
```

afterwards I updated texlive and then mdframed changed to version 0.9e and many packages are loaded which were not loaded before:

```
mdframed.sty 2011/09/11 v0.9e: mdframed
...
zref-abspage.sty 2011/03/18 v2.21 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty 2011/03/18 v2.21 Module base for zref (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty 2011/04/07 v1.3 Defining keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty 2011/04/22 v0.16 Utilities of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifpdf.sty 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
auxhook.sty 2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
atbegshi.sty 2011/01/30 v1.15 At begin shipout hook (HO)
md-frame-0.mdf 2011/09/10 v0.9e: md-frame-0
```

now it compiles without error.

Comment: You need to remove a blank line after : `The url package provides a failsafe way to print
urls with characters not allowed by LaTeX.`

Comment: This code compiles just fine for me using TeXLive 2011.

Comment: @Altermundus: why should it be exactly this line. I can also remove the line with `\textsc{\textbf{bold small caps}}` and it compiles.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I am using TeX Live 2011 on windows 7 64 bit with latest updates.

Comment: How do you compile this document? `pdflatex`, `latex`, ...?

Comment: @MartinScharrer: with pdflatex

Comment: The document compiles fine with miktex too and doesn't use up a significant input stack. But when verbatim listings are involved the exact coding (of e.g. spaces and end-of-lines) can matter, so you should perhaps put your example together with the log-file in a zip-file on the net somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the code as provided compiles fine for me using TeXLive2011, so perhaps you are using an older version of some package. What follows is not a direct solution to the problem reported here, but rather an alternate way of displaying code:

If you want to show LaTeX code and it's output you should consider using [the `showexpl` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/showexpl) along with [the`listings` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) as that produces very nice output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{showexpl}
    \lstset{
        backgroundcolor=\color{yellow},
        basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,% print whole listing small
        keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries\underbar,
        numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=2, numbersep=5pt,
        showstringspaces=false
    }
    \lstloadlanguages{[LaTeX]TeX}


\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}[pos=b]
The standard commands for font attributes:  
\textbf{bold}, \textit{italic}, \textsl{slanted},
\textsf{sans serif}, \textsc{small caps} and
\texttt{monospaced typewrite}.
And any combination of them:
\textit{\textbf{bold italic}},
\textsl{\textbf{bold slanted}},
\textsf{\textbf{bold sans serif}},
\textsc{\textbf{bold small caps}}
\textsl{\textsf{sans serif slanted}}. 
\end{LTXexample}

The url package provides a failsafe way to print
urls with characters not allowed by LaTeX.

\begin{LTXexample}
\url{http://www.dante.de}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

Comment: showexpl can not be modified in its style and using LTXexample within an iscsdef is not allowed (as with any verbatim material). So what I do is more or less an alternative version of LTXexample where the code is exported to a file before.